# How to get the object from GridView itemClick

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have an Activity named **countryActivity** and a model class named Country. I want to set the values in model class and store each object in arraylist, as well as show the object values in a gridview. When the items will be clicked then i want to retrieve the objects. Below are my codes. Where did i go wrong or what to do? help me out plz?

**activity_country.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context=".CountryActivity" >


 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/nTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="Name" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/aTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nTextView"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:text="About" />

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/CountryNameEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/nTextView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/nTextView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/nTextView"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
 </EditText>

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/CountryAboutEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/CountryNameEditText"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/aTextView"
    android:ems="10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/saveCountryButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/CountryAboutEditText"
    android:layout_below="@+id/CountryAboutEditText"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:text="Save" 
    android:onClick="saveCountry"
    />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/countryGridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/saveCountryButton"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:numColumns="2">
</GridView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**CountryActivity.java**

```
 public class CountryActivity extends Activity 
{
ArrayList<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>();
Country aCountry;

EditText CountryNameTxtBox;
EditText CountryAboutTxtBox;
GridView countrygGridView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_country);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.

    CountryNameTxtBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.CountryNameEditText);
    CountryAboutTxtBox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.CountryAboutEditText);
    countrygGridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.countryGridView);

}
if((txtName!="" || txtName!=null) &&  (txtAbout!="" || txtAbout != null))
    {
      aCountry = new Country(txtName, txtAbout);
      countries.add(aCountry);
    }

    showGrid();

}


public void showGrid()
{
     ArrayList<Country> list2 = new ArrayList<Country>();

    for(Country arrCountry : countries)
    { 
             list2.add(aCountry);

    } 


      ArrayAdapter<Country> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<Country>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list2);
      countrygGridView.setAdapter(adapter2);


 countrygGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
  {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) 
    {
     aCountry = (Country) v.getTag();
      for(Country mCountry: countries)
      {
       if(countries.contains(aCountry))
        {
        Toast.makeText(CountryActivity.this, "match", 2000).show();
        }
          }
         }
     });
   }
 }
```

**Country.java (the model class)**

```
public class Country 
{

private String name;
private String about;
    ArrayList<City> cities;

public Country()
{
    cities = new ArrayList<City>();
}

   public Country(String name, String about)
{
    this.name= name;
    this.about = about;
}


public int getNoOfCities()
{
    return cities.size();
}


public long getNoOfCitizens()
{
       Long aPop= 0L;
    for(City aCity: cities)
    {
             aPop += aCity.getPopulation();
    }
    return aPop;
}



public String getName(){
    return name;

} 
public String getAbout(){
    return about;

} 
}
```

Comment: Think this will solve it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164478/customadapter-for-object-isnt-working

Answer (score 1):

In the `onItemClick` method, just do `list2.get(position)` and you have your country.

Comment: But i am adding the object in arrayList and adapter, so in girdview its showing the object itself. I want to show the values in gridview(name and about from Country.java class). and again when  listItems in gridview clicked i want to get the object so i can my model class to retrieve the values from object.

Comment: Then you have to create a custom adapter that does that. The simple ArrayAdapter can't know what you want to display.

Comment: did i do i right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21164478/customadapter-for-object-isnt-working     :-)

Answer (score 0):

Fix on your code

```
     countrygGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
      {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) 
        {
                 Country cnt = (Country)countrygGridView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
         });
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `onItemClick` for the `GridView` you will get the **position** of the item you clicked

```
Country country = countries.get(position);
```

[Refer this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

Answer (score 0):

(In onItemClick method, just put:

```
Country aCountry = countries.get(position);
```

You get a match for sure, you don't need to manually check in the list, because the list you set in the adapter is used, in the same order, when retrieving items in your grid view.

You should compare strings by using "equals", not "==", use && instead of ||, because I suppose you want all conditions to happen simultaneously and check for null before checking an actual value of your string, so replace:

```
if((txtName!="" || txtName!=null) &&  (txtAbout!="" || txtAbout != null))
```

With:

```
if(txtName!=null && !txtName.equals("") &&  txtAbout != null && !txtAbout.equals(""))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to displays **name** and **about** using ArrayAdapter, you have to override toString method in Country class.

```
String toString() {
  return this.name + " " + this.about;
}
```